# nuxt 3 generates not working dist by default?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying nuxt 3 and after

```
nuxi init .
yarn
yarn generate
cd dist
http-server
```

seems generated dist by nuxt is not working, in browser

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , e.useRuntimeConfig) is not a function
    at Object.668 (3553192.js:1:751)
    at n (2b86c0d.js:1:125)
    at Object.560 (ff68974.js:7:29773)
    at n (2b86c0d.js:1:125)
    at t (3553192.js:1:1207)
    at 3553192.js:1:1232
    at Function.n.O (2b86c0d.js:1:467)
    at 3553192.js:1:1248
    at o (2b86c0d.js:1:1135)
    at 3553192.js:1:43
```

what is going wrong...

Comment: Isn't it `serve .output` rather? It's written how you can preview after the generation.

Comment: you should use `nuxt preview` (`yarn preview / npm run preview` by default). It will do the `serve .output` command as @kissu wrote. It will probably install `serve` package.

Comment: @fakie no need to even install it, it can be run through `npx`.